# LBYouTubeView and HD?

Tags: ios, ipad, uiwebview, youtube

I am using [larcus94's LBYouTubeView](https://github.com/larcus94/LBYouTubeView) in my app to present a tutorial video (i chose it instead of UIWebView and embedded player to track view dismiss notifications) but the highest quality it provides looks pretty bad, especially on retina display. Is there any legit way to get the HD quality with this control or detect whether embedded player in UIWebView has been closed?